# Gas cost function execution error

Tags: gas

Gas requirement of function FarmToken.balance is infinite:
If the gas requirement of a function is higher than the block gas limit, it cannot be executed.

This is the complete Farm Token ethereum.org smart contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/9b3710465583284b8c4c5d2245749246bb2e0094/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/9b3710465583284b8c4c5d2245749246bb2e0094/contracts/utils/Address.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/9b3710465583284b8c4c5d2245749246bb2e0094/contracts/token/ERC20/SafeERC20.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/9b3710465583284b8c4c5d2245749246bb2e0094/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract FarmToken is ERC20 {
    using Address for address;
    using SafeMath for uint256; // As of Solidity v0.8.0, mathematical operations can be done safely without the need for SafeMath
    using SafeERC20 for IERC20;

    IERC20 public token;

    constructor(address _token) public ERC20(){
        token = IERC20(_token);
    }

    function balance() public view returns (uint256) {
        return token.balanceOf(address(this));
    }

    function deposit(uint256 _amount) public {
        // Amount must be greater than zero
        require(_amount > 0, "amount cannot be 0");
    
        // Transfer MyToken to smart contract
        token.safeTransferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amount);
    
        // Mint FarmToken to msg sender
        _mint(msg.sender, _amount);
    }
    
    function withdraw(uint256 _amount) public {
    // Burn FarmTokens from msg sender
    _burn(msg.sender, _amount);

    // Transfer MyTokens from this smart contract to msg sender
    token.safeTransfer(msg.sender, _amount);
    }
    
    function () external payable {}

}

// this is the ERC20 contract code:

pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/9b3710465583284b8c4c5d2245749246bb2e0094/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/9b3710465583284b8c4c5d2245749246bb2e0094/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Detailed.sol";

/**
 * @title SimpleToken
 * @dev Very simple ERC20 Token example, where all tokens are pre-assigned to the creator.
 * Note they can later distribute these tokens as they wish using `transfer` and other
 * `ERC20` functions.
 */
contract SimpleToken is ERC20, ERC20Detailed {

    /**
     * @dev Constructor that gives msg.sender all of existing tokens.
     */
    constructor () public ERC20Detailed("SimpleToken", "SIM", 18) {
        _mint(msg.sender, 10000 * (10 ** uint256(decimals())));
    }
}
```

Comment: Has `token` been initialized to a non-zero address? What code is used to measure the gas required?

Comment: thanks for your response, i don´t have code to measure the gas required. in the farm token ERC20 example in the ethereum.org don´t have it . The code example here is the same ethereum.org

Comment: There are a couple of things that can make the function revert: 1/ token is points to a non-contract address, 2/ invalid opcode when deployed to a private testnet with missing opcodes.

Comment: Thanks! i put the complete smart contract code, can you show me a code with this specification you say? this is the ethereum.org example code for farm token contract

Comment: Are you looking at "Solidity Static Analysis"? The warning are usually quite generic. In your case it might fail when token = 0x0 (or a non-contract address), but if you initialize it properly it should work. The tool without context cannot determine which is the right case and warn 'just in case'.

Comment: Yes this message is in the "Solidity Static Analysis" , i have initialized the farm token contract over the ERC20 token contract :

Comment: I add the ERC20 contract code, where the farm token is initializing

Comment: And this is the ERC20 contact deployed in Ropsten testnet : 0x1bb05ccfbea54caf384a4782b060563c45617710

Comment: This is the etherescan token find: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tokens?q=0x1bb05ccfbea54caf384a4782b060563c45617710

Comment: I see i have deployed correctly the Farm token over the ERC20 token address, how can i test a deposit in this farm token?

Comment: It is a tool limitation there isn't much you can do about it. If the address is a valid token it should be fine. You can write unit test to execute the function and be sure they work.

Comment: Excelent, can you give me info about unit test in ethereum i don´t have knowledge about it please, how can i do this test?

Comment: It is better if you ask in a new question about unit testing, first search if there's an existing question.